# I'm coding a discord bot and getting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, replit

I'm asking the person a question, and they reply with the time they want to get pinged at. I push all the data to an array after the collector has ended, then split the last string at ":" to get the hour and minute for the ping, then save it to a variable called res 2. The file in which I'm having trouble with:

```
const mongo = require('../mongo');
const data = require('../data');
const DiscordJS = require('discord.js');


module.exports = {
    commands: ['register'],
    callback: async (message, arguments, text) => {
        const { author } = message;
        const { id } = author;
        
        let result;
            await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
                try {
                    try {

                        res = await data.findOne({
                            _id: message.guild.id
                        })
    
                    } finally {
                        
                        if (res) {
                            try {
                                console.log('running findOne()')
                                result = await data.findOne({
                                    _id: id,
                                    guildId: message.guild.id
                                });
                                console.log(result);
                            } finally {
                            if (result) {
                                message.channel.send('Already enrolled in this server. Looking to change your birthday? Run b:change instead.');
                                mongoose.connection.close();
                            } else {
                                    try {
            
                                        let questions = [
                                            'What is your birth month (M or MM)?',
                                            'What is your birth date (D or DD)?',
                                            'What time would you like to be pinged? (MILITARY TIME EST) (HH:MM)'
                                        ];
            
                                        let counter = 0;
            
                                        const filter = (m) => m.author.id == message.author.id;
            
                                        const collector = new DiscordJS.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {
                                            max: questions.length,
                                            
                                        })
            
                                        message.channel.send(questions[counter++]);
                                        collector.on('collect', m => {
                                            if (counter < questions.length) {
                                                m.channel.send(questions[counter++]);
                                            }
                                        })
            
                                       
            
                                        collector.on('end', async (collected) => {
                                             let results = {};
                                            let counter = 0;
                                            collected.forEach((value) => {
                                                results.push(value.content);
                                                console.log(value.content)
                                            });
    
                                            let res2;
                                            if (results[2] !== null) {
                                              res2 = results[2].split(':');
                                            }
                                            
                                            console.log('results[0].length : ' + results[0].length);
                                            console.log('results[1].length : ' + results[1].length);
                                            console.log('res2[0].length : ' + res2[0].length);
                                            console.log('res2[1].length : ' + res2[1].length);
            
                                        if ((results[0].length < 3 && results[0].length > 0) && (results[1].length < 3 && results[1].length > 0) && (res2[0].length > 0 && res2[0].length < 3) && (res2[1].length > 0 && res2[1].length < 3)) {
                                            
                                            let month = parseInt(results[0]) - 1;
                                            let date = parseInt(results[1]);
                                            let hour = parseInt(res2[0]);
                                            let minute = parseInt(res2[1]);
    
                                            console.log(month, date, hour, minute);
                                            if ((!isNaN(month) && !isNaN(date)) && (!isNaN(hour) && !isNaN(minute))) {
    
                                                
                                                    await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
                                                        try {
                                                            await new data({
                                                                _id: id,
                                                                month,
                                                                date,
                                                                hour,
                                                                minute,
                                                                guildId: message.guild.id
                                                            }, {
                                                                upsert: true
                                                            }).save()
    
                                                            message.reply(`All done! You will be pinged on ${month + 1}/${date} at ${hour}:${minute}. Thank you!`);
                                                        } finally {
                                                            mongoose.connection.close()
                                                        }
                                                        
                                                    }).catch(err => message.reply('There was an error. Try again.'));
                                                 
                                                
                                            } else {
                                                message.reply('Please enter all values in the correct format');
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            message.reply('Please enter the values in the correct format');
                                        }
                                        }).catch(err => mesage.reply('Sorry, something went wrong, please try again. The error : ' + err));
            
                    
            
                                        
                                        
                                    } finally {
                                        mongoose.connection.close();
                                    }
                                    };
                            }
                        } else {
                            message.reply(`An admin hasn't set me up yet. Please ask an admin to run b:setup`);
                        }
                
                
                

              


                
            };
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
    }).catch(err => message.reply('Something went wrong. Please try again later'));
    
    
    }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble at res2 = results[2].split(":")

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem line, and it isn't elsewhere in your code? If so, maybe try `if (results[2])` and see what happens.

Comment: I guess `collected` is empty, because you have defined `results` as an object instead of an array, and if the `collected.forEach` would have ran you'd get an error saying push is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your if condition. You are simply checking
`arr[2] === null` which will be true if arr[2] does not exist since it will be `undefined` so `undefined !== null` will result to true.

So, what you can do is instead of checking of `null`, you can check for undefined. So, your condition will be `arr[2] !== undefined` or simple `if(arr[2])` will also work.

Edit:
As @derpirscher suggested, we can check for `typeof arr[2]` whether it is of "string" type or not. This will handle both cases - arr[2] exists and the arr[2] value is a string. So, the final condition would be `if(typeof arr[2] === "string")`

Comment: Even better would be checking `if (typeof results[2] === "string")`, because that would handle both cases (ie `null` and `undefined`) but will execute the body if `results[2] === ''` (ie the empty string)

Comment: @derpirscher correct, let me edit my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! I will test both solutions.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work. I still get the same error. I tried checking if arr[2] was truthy and whether typeof === 'string'.

Comment: @AFellowFriendlyMemer can you try logging the value of arr[2]. What value you are getting in the log?

Comment: the code stops running before it logs the value for some reason